# DynamoDB mapper: update only not-null properties

Tags: amazon-web-services, updates, amazon-dynamodb

I am using the mapper provided by the AWS SDK, with Java. 
I need to update record on DynamoDB: is there any way, using the mapper, to avoid that a null property of a mapped entity is stored on DynamoDB, overwriting the old value?

I try to explain my question with an example.
I have a java entity with three properties: id, a, b. It is mapped to a DynamoDB table with hashKey only, on field id.
On DynamoDB it is stored a record {"id":"1", "a":"aa"}.
After an update called on an entity with id:1, a:null and b:"bb", I find on DynamoDB a record {"id":"1", "b":"bb"}.

Any solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will be very interested in the new `SaveBehavior` strategy, recently introduced in v1.5.4. The new `SaveBehavior` strategy is called `UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES`. This new `SaveBehavior` is very similar to the existing `UPDATE` strategy. The only difference is that any attributes sent with null values will not be removed from the item in DynamoDB. [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.html) is the link to the JavaDoc.